# How to compile and execute a java app without IDE?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using Intellij Idea to develop this simple java app below. When I execute it from the IDE, it works. But if I compile and execute from the linux terminal, I get this:

```
# javac -classpath kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar prova.java 
# java prova -classpath kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar
Error: mpossible to initialize the main test class
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback
```

---

```
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;

public class prova {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("start");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092");
        properties.setProperty("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.setProperty("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        // Crea producer:
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);

        try
        {
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("topicthreepart", "chiave4" , "buonasera" ), new Callback() {
                public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        System.out.println("wrong");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("correct");
                        System.out.println("timestamp: "+ metadata.timestamp());
                        System.out.println("topic: "+ metadata.topic());
                        System.out.println("offset: "+ metadata.offset());
                        System.out.println("partition: "+ metadata.partition());
                    }
                }
            }).get();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: you have to build it to jar and then run jar file

Comment: If you want to do without IDE, you can do it via command line but you need to build the jar using build tools i.e. maven, gradle or sbt to include the dependent libraries.